# I could not able to access a <div> through Javascript,if there is only a <div></div> in a HTML page

Tags: javascript

I have written below code in a HTML file name as test.html

```
<div id="dd"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("dd").innerHTML="fdfdfd";
  alert(document.getElementById("dd").innerHTML);
</script>
```

The above code is not working. Can someone help me. What is the reason ?

If I put a `<body>` tag or write anything, then it works fine and Its working in Google chrome.

Comment: its working for me, see http://jsfiddle.net/DVMK8/

Comment: I'd advise you to get a good book, and have a good read.

Comment: @tarun: if you have no real additional value to the comment, don't make one!

Comment: @Priyabrata, I'm confused. Define not working. Does that mean the script isn't running, or that you're not seeing what you want in the alert box?

Comment: @Tarun, Its not matter of reading good book,If you can answer ,please give the reason.I am new to Javascript.

Comment: @Priyabrata It's absolutely a matter of reading a good book. That's great that you want to learn all by yourself, but you're probably going to ask a million no brainer questions. I think it's best to read a book and then ask questions if you still need help.

Comment: @renevdkooi I posted the comment, considering @Priyabrata does not have enough knowledge of the subject. My apologies if it sounded rude.

Comment: @Priyabrata Since you are new,  advised you to get a good book and have a thorough read. As far as your question is concerned, If you can elaborate a bit more as to what functionality you want your code to do, maybe we can help better.

Comment: At this stage, it is less a matter of reading a good book and more a matter of asking a good question. What does 'not working' mean? What would be different if it was 'working'? How does adding a `<body>` tag fix it? If it works in Chrome, is that all the time or just after adding `<body>`? Do other browsers behave differently?

Comment: Tarun, suggestions to "read a book" are often best delivered with an URL to a favorite book you think would be applicable. :)

Comment: Priyabrat's question is that he is supposed to get an alert with blank, but rather he is finding error that "document. GetElementById("dd") is null". Why is it? As I know from the code that it should show a blank alert, instead why is it showing error in mozilla firefox.

Comment: @arun, that makes a whole lot more sense, I couldn't understand what he was trying to ask. I would imagine that different browsers have their own rules with dealing with script. Chrome chooses to handle the error different then firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that your asking JavaScript to tell you what's inside of an element before you put something in it? Try putting the alert line underneath the other.

Do this:

```
<div id="dd"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("dd").innerHTML="fdfdfd";
  alert(document.getElementById("dd").innerHTML);
</script>
```

Here is a working example:[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LmbW4/)

Comment: @Priyabrata, when you say it doesn't work what does that mean? Does it mean no alert box shows up? Does it mean an alert box shows up, is blank, but you want it to show the innerHTML of `dd`?

Comment: @Priyabrata, Like I said, put `alert(document.getElementById("dd").innerHTML);` at the end.

Comment: @Nick,No no ,My question is the above code is not working in Mozilla FF.

Comment: @Priyabrata, which code? Your original code or how I told you to modify it?

Comment: @Priyabrata, I already told you it wouldn't work. It won't work in any browser. Are you still confused on how fix your code?

Comment: @Priyabrata, click the link in my answer, it does work. It has to be something else. Edit your question and post the full html.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/xqa9D/

The way you've written this code, the code should
1. pop up an alert with an empty string, and 2. replace the contents of `#dd` with "fdfdfd."

The code does this.  What isn't working?

Comment: @bigmattyh It alerts a textbox with nothing in it. It works as it's supposed to, but not as he intended for it to work.

Comment: @Priyabrata, we can't help much unless you provide more details about what you say isn't working.

Comment: @bigmattyh,have run this code (test.html) in your browser(Mozilla FF)?

Comment: @bigmattyh, It seems pretty obvious that he's getting an alert with nothing in it. He is expecting to get the html of element id `dd`.

Comment: @Nick, No, it isn't obvious *at all*.  His pithy responses aren't providing more than the least bit of guidance as to what he is trying to do, or why it might be broken on his end.  The code "works" on Chrome and Firefox, but he keeps saying it's broken -- but it's impossible to tell why because he hasn't articulated what his intentions are. It's important to remember that we're trying to help him, and that he needs to put in a little more effort in communication to make that possible.

Comment: @bigmattyh, I was wrong, apparently he knows the code is wrong but wants to know why in some browsers it shows nothing, but in firefox it just gives him an error. If that is the case I have no idea why this question was brought up. It's not a case of the alert should show the value of the element before it is set, it is a case of why one errors and another shows nothing. Like you said though, his communication was horrible.